# How to implement an Anti-Corruption Layer correctly

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm starting with DDD philosophy and I'd like to implement an integration with a legacy system that we have here. In my researches in the internet, I found some articles and samples but I must to admit: is pretty hard to understand how to do that integration correctly.

Before to ask this question, I did a search here but the results were not useful for me, so I'd like to know if is possible to send or show me a implementation sample of an ACL.

Here I have this items:

- The Legacy system
- The legacy database (I need to access)
- The new application that will be created using the DDD approach

The initial idea is to access that database throughout NHibernate, creating just some the needed mapping classes, the domain entities and implement the business rules. According to Eric Evans, this strategy is called [Bubble Context][1]. I think this strategy will solve my problem, but I need some sample to do that in a right way.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you read Eric Evans's book "Domain Driven Design", there is a section about acl. Acl is actually an example of applying adapter pattern in DDD.

Comment: One suggestion I have from personal experience is to not jump to accessing a legacy database with NHibernate because it may not be worthwhile. Instead, focus on encapsulating the legacy system with a service which can then be accessed by new app through ACL.

Answer (score 8):

The ACL is a pattern and not just the piece of code. In what you described you didn't say do you have strong dependencies upon legacy system or you just want to have some independent piece of code built into current system? With this you could decide will be your ACL just a service to database or will it incorporate some wrapping upon legacy system logic?

The actual pieces that you'd put into the ALC are highly depend on your implementation.
There is a generic schema of what you're asking for:
[image]

You could find more info in [Eric Evan's talk](http://dddcommunity.org/library/evans_2011_2/2).